# Unable to ssh inside ec2 instance (AWS-Linux) from codebuild (using buildspec)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, devops, aws-codebuild

I want to ssh inside my ec2 instance from my buildspec to run 2 bash scripts inside my server but am getting:

```
Running command ssh -i ~/.ssh/xx_key ec2-user@$EC2_HOST "cd /var/www/xx-api && ./xx-api-deploy.sh"
Warning: Permanently added '13.aa.xx.yy' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
[Container] Command did not exit successfully ssh -i ~/.ssh/xx_key ec2-user@$EC2_HOST "cd /var/www/xx-api && ./xx-api-deploy.sh" exit status 255
```

This is my current buildspec:

```
phases:

    commands:
      - export EC2_ACCESS_KEY=$EC2_ACCESS_KEY_PARAM
      - echo "$EC2_ACCESS_KEY" > ~/.ssh/xx_key
      - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
      - chmod 400 ~/.ssh/xx_key
      - echo -e "Host $EC2_HOST\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config

  build:

    commands:
      - ssh -i ~/.ssh/xx_key ec2-user@$EC2_HOST "cd /var/www/xx-api && ./xx-api-deploy.sh"
      - ssh -i ~/.ssh/xx_key ec2-user@$EC2_HOST "cd /var/www/xx-api && ./yy-api-deploy.sh"
```

I can access my server locally and have made plenty of changes inside it so it is not a problem of access via port 22.
I have also changed permissions in my authorized_keys inside /home/[user]/.ssh/authorized_keys in my server such as:
**PermitRootLogin no,
PubkeyAuthentication yes,
GSSAPIAuthentication yes,
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no,
UsePAM yes,
PasswordAuthentication yes**
and finally `chmod 0600 /home/[username]/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `chmod 0700 /home/your_home/.ssh`

Comment: You can add a `-v` argument to ssh to make it print more diagnostic details about what it is doing.